# How can I config a backend for all other hosts in ngxin ingress?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, default, nginx-ingress, host

Here is my ingress config yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mydomain.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: backend_default
      port:
        number: 8000
  rules:
    - host: domain1.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend1
                port:
                  number: 8888
    - host: domain2.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend2
                port:
                  number: 8888
```

I have domain1.com and domain2.com point to my k8s. And they works fine.
Now I have domain3.com and domain4.com and a lot of other domain I want to point them to k8s too. I'd like to point them to the same backend.
I don't want to add multi lines. How can I set a default backend so that I can point my domain3.com, domain4.com and other domains to.
I have tried the defaultBackend, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hostname [wildcards](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards) which will be useful in this scenario to configure a **default backend** for all the **hosts** . Also, update the ingress config yaml file in the below format as per your domain requirement.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  -host: "*.foo.com"
   http:
     paths:
     -pathType: Prefix
      path: "/foo"
      backend:
        service:
         name: backend1
         port:
           number: 8888
```

Hope the above information is useful to you.